# Spring Web MVC Application Cannot Find Resources

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I am using netbeans as my IDE for developing basic web application. I successfully added external files as resources such as pictures and CSS files. They were working fine untill today, suddenly they are not being found by netbeans. Following is the error I am getting when debugging

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method not allowed).
```

Here is how I have initialized the MVC resources in XML config file.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="31556926"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

And here is how I am using it, in JSP file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>'>
```

So what could be wrong. Why it has stopped suddenly ? Thanks for any pointer.

======== EDIT ===========

Here is my web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
       /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Following (already shown) two lines are in applicationContext.xml

```
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="31556926"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

And here is my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myURL", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String MyControllerGET(HttpServletRequest request, Model model)
{
     // some code here....nothing fancy, just harcoding some values
}
```

Comment: I don't know a whole lot about spring and it's routing mechanics but it seems the http `GET` request is not allowed for some reason. Hope I pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: I will need to see the code of your controller as well as your `web.xml` file. There seems to be some URI-based configuration that prevents properly serving static resources through GET requests.

Comment: @Jeff....please read my update.

Comment: try to remove `<mvc:annotation-driven />`